# Security of Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

Just a question about setting cookies.

Say your web application is getting information about a users location and seeing if they are in x area. If they are then we can show them y content, or else don't show them.

If you wanted to store that information in a cookie so that later the server/application will read the cookie and have certain assets/web components be showed to the user, could the user theoretically set that cookie to set themselves as a valid user in the region, thus being able to see content they shouldn't? If they saw the setup of the cookie that had been set (i.e. cookie key = userInValidRegion, val = true/yes/something), could they follow the same format and set it themselves?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the browser owner can set cookies. You can't trust browsers for that. For "geofencing" you really cannot trust anything; people can use VPNs etc.

Comment: You can use jwts to prevent users from tampering with cookie data, however nothing prevents the user from spoofing their location when the jwt is being generated.

Comment: If you set the cookie as HttpOnly, secure, and SameSite, it makes it more difficult for the user to set the cookie themselves. Cookies are not a good method, by themselves, for security.